# How do I create a Pivot table in Pandas using the default index as the pivot index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the below data frame:

```
   Dataset Scores
0   times_pregnant  6.000
1   plasma_glucose_concentration    148.000
2   diastolic_blood_pressure    72.000
3   triceps_thickness   35.000
4   2_hour_serum_insulin    0.000
... ... ...
7828    BMI 30.400
7829    diabetes_pedigreen  0.315
7830    age 23.000
7831    diabetes    0.000
7832    times_pregnant  1.000
```

I want to turn the "Dataset" column contents into column headers and have the "Scores" column as values. When I try to pivot without specifying an index it just gives me the average of all the scores under each column header, but I want each score listed under each column header.

Current result:

```
Dataset 2_hour_serum_insulin    BMI age diabetes    diabetes_pedigreen  diastolic_blood_pressure    plasma_glucose_concentration    times_pregnant  triceps_thickness
Scores  79.799479   31.992578   33.240885   0.348958    0.471876    69.105469   120.894531  3.845052    20.536458
```

Desired result:

```
times_pregnant  BMI    Age
2               23.50  45
4               30.40  23
3               41.50  23
5               25.40  42
```

Pandas gives you a default unique index but I don't understand how to set this as my index to allow all my scores to be listed out.

Is pivoting the best way to do this?

Comment: Please provide the TEXT version of the dataframe you have along with the expected output. It'll improve you chances of getting a response.

Comment: easy way of doing this is df[:50].to_clipboard()

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each woman has the same amount of scores, you could add an index for each woman and pivot on it (df is your dataframe):

```
 u = df['Dataset'].nunique()
 df['women_idx'] = [int(x/u) for x in range(df.shape[0])]

 df.pivot(columns='Dataset', index='women_idx')
```

Comment: hey - this gives an error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: tested it on a manually fixed OCR of what you posted, send over some real data or post the error and I'll try to help, in any case try to understand the logic and see if it suits your needs

Comment: it seems that in thefull data some women have less/more readings (makes sense), do you have any way of idetifying the rows belonging to each woman (an id column from some sort)?

Comment: I changed pivot to pivot_table and this seems to have given exactly what i was looking for. I removed a few rows that shouldn't have been there meaning that each woman had the exact same number of rows relating to them. This indexed for every set of stats. I'm not 100% sure I understand what the code has actually done though, so if someone could explain in laymen's terms I'd appreciate it

Comment: the first 2 llines are just for creating an id for each women (0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2... if each women had 3 tests). Think the diffrence between pivot and pivot_table is that pivot fails on duplicate entries while pivot_table aggragetes the 2 entries (mean by default) and hence could just work on numerical vars